# Find name of app

Tags: actionscript-3, reboot

FlashBuilder Flex

In my reboot code, I have the following line:

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("app:/playerAir.exe");
```

It works as long as the app's name doesn't change

I want an automated way to find this app's name to change that `"playerAir"`.

The reasons:
If I change the name, I have to change it in the reboot function too
If a client has more than one versions of the file (`playerAir.exe`, `playerAir1.exe`, `playerAir2.exe`) then it'll launch the wrong one.

How could I make it so it changes accordingly to the name the app has?

Comment: Did you find a solution ever?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately since the project wasn't mine I dont have access to it anymore. The solution was what you said with an extra line or 2.

Comment: If you can recall the extra line or two, it may be helpful for future visitors if you shared that.  If you feel my answer satisfies the question, consider marking it as the accepted answer which helps people with a similar question find a solution faster - it also increases your and my reputations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of the reboot function is as follows:

```
public function Reboot():void                                                                   ///
        {                                                                                               ///
            var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();     ///
            var app:WindowedApplication=WindowedApplication(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);           ///
            var swf:String=stage.loaderInfo.url.substring(0,stage.loaderInfo.url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);   ///get swf's path (- *name*.swf)
            swf=swf+app.applicationID;                                                                  ///adds applicationID after the path. ex: app:/ -> becomes -> app:/m7tvPlayerAir
            var d:Array = File.applicationDirectory.getDirectoryListing();                              ///get all files in the directory
            var exe:String;                                                                             ///the executable (.exe, .app, .dmg) (multiplatform)
            for each(var f:File in d){                                                                  ///checks all files in the directory
                if(f.url.indexOf(swf)==0 && (f.url.indexOf(".dmg") > -1 || f.url.indexOf(".app") > -1 || f.url.indexOf(".exe") > -1)){///if any of them has the same directory and name, and has 1 of the extensions
                    exe=f.url;                                                                          ///found the executable
                    break;                                                                              ///stops the loop
                }///end If
            }///end for
            trace(exe);                                                                                 ///
            if(exe==null){                                                                              ///will just close the application if it doesn't find the file
                (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication).exit();                                               ///
            }else{                                                                                      ///if it did find a file
                var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(exe);                             ///
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;                                             ///
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.documentsDirectory;                    ///
                var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();                                        ///
                (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication).exit();                                               ///
                process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);                                                ///
            }///end else
        }///end function
```

(Hey this is Ohciarob, I forgot my password)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to determine the application name with the `url` property of the stage's [loaderinfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#url) object.

This will point to the swf file being run, which by default will be the same name as the executable.

So, if you know your app has an extension of .exe, this would likely work:

```
var path:String = stage.loaderInfo.url.replace(".swf",".exe");
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(path);
```

---

If you are running a multi-platform app, you could walk the application directory looking for the appropriate application extension:

```
//get the swf path minus the 'swf'
var swf:String = stage.loaderInfo.url.substring(0,stage.loaderInfo.url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

//get all the files in the application directory
var d = File.applicationDirectory.getDirectoryListing();

//find your executable (this is just a sample of how to do this, ideally you'd have a compile time constant to indicate the extension of your current build)
var exe:String;
for each(var f:File in d){
    if(f.url.indexOf(swf) === 0 && (f.url.indexOf(".dmg") > -1 || f.url.indexOf(".app") > -1 || f.url.indexOf(".exe") > -1)){
        exe = f.url; //found the executable path
        break; //stop the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets say I run AIR app on Linux or MacOS. On these systems binaries does not come in EXEs. Your move?

Comment: @Organis - The OP has not indicated this is a multi-platform app.  If you have a helpful suggestion, by all means suggest it.

Comment: I googled most logical ideas which are NativeApplication and NativeProcess prior to asking you, but it seems there is no startup info about the AIR process, or it is hidden at some place not that obvious. That's why I asked.

Comment: I've never stumbled across it anywhere in my travels and if it's there it's not documented (or at least not documented well).  Perhaps someone else though will come up with a more elegant solution than this or know of an explicit way to find the application name.

Comment: What if the swf doesn't change it's name, however the exe does? Any way of checking? I may have figured it out, testing now

Comment: I don't know of a built in way to figure out which exe they are using.  You could likely do it with an ANE (native extension) by linking a dll file made in .NET  - if you just want the most recent version, you can find all .exe's in the application directory and use the one with the newest date created (or see if one matches the date of the swf file).